# gmail whitelist IP/domain name for emails sent from workstation

Tags: gmail

How can I configure Gmail to whitelist the IP/domain name of my workstation so that I can send emails from it without being blocked or delayed?

LONG VERSION: I have a Linux Ubuntu 14.04 workstation at work, and for some long running jobs, I place a simple command-line `mail` statement on completion so I can receive an email notifier. E.g.:

```
echo -e "Job XYZ completed on $workstation" | mail -s "/home/user/script.sh" "myusername@gmail.com"
```

It's worked well for a while, but recently Gmail may have changed the rules, and I can't see the emails anymore, or sometimes they come back after 8 hours or so.

How can I configure my Gmail to allow these emails to go through?

Comment: Are they in your spam bucket? Then simply mark them as "Not spam". If they're not showing up at all, then the problem is somewhere before the mail gets to Google.

Comment: The email go through, but with several hours of delay.

Comment: That's got nothing to do with Gmail, then. The problem is upstream. Diagnosing email routing issues is beyond the scope of this site.